# Load data from a list of lines using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to load a pandas data frame from a list of text lines, much like I would do using the pa.read_csv() function.

So if I have a text file like this:

```
col1 col2
1 2
3 4
```

I can load it into a pandas data frame like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pa
>>> pa.read_csv('test.txt')
  col1 col2
0       1 2
1       3 4
```

My question is, can I load an array like this:

```
>>> lines = ['col1 col2', '1 2', '3 4']
```

And use some function to load that as a dataframe, as in the case with the file?

Comment: Aside: remember to either set the right delimiter or use `delim_whitespace`-- right now, you're not separating the columns correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This was just a toy example, but you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import StringIO

pa.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(lines.join('\n')))
```

Answer (score 2):

more modern (python 3x moved StringIO into io, and the syntax of join changed):

```
import pandas as pa
from io import StringIO

pa.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32306855)

Comment: @alexpdev: It looks like an answer to me, though it would be certainly be more _useful_ of an answer if the author made an [edit] to better explain why it's different from other approaches, and what new capabilities they're taking advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'd need Pandas to do this, you can do this just with normal Python:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [l.rstrip() for l in f.readlines()]

print(lines)
```

The output:

```
['col1 col2', '1 2', '3 4']
```